# Android Apps Storage

Tags: android, storage

if one develops an app for android or so and the apps is being designed

In such a way that it stores some data in it.But it needs some db to store na , But if no db is integrated , is there any possible soln that any data that an user enter

Can store in the apps itself

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Android fully supports SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

If data is more it is better to use database. Otherwise you can save some information in strings.xml , like some constants. DanS has provided you link for database already.